# .NET Core HttpRequest Middleware and AccessToken mechanism?

Tags: .net-core, jwt, access-token, asp.net-core-webapi

I am really confused about generating access token and use it. Generation of Access Token should be placed in Controller or in middleware? If someone explain this to me, I would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly generating access token, refresh token, etc all should happen in a **real authorization server** for more info  [http://authguidance.com](http://authguidance.com/)

but by saying that even i generated JWT token within my app as well...
this is how i did in .net core 2.0

in startup.cs

### ConfigureServices

```
            var securityKey = "asdasdasdasdasdasddsda123123132123123";// your own key
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(securityKey);

        var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidAudiences = new string[]
            {
                tokenSetting.Audience
            },
            ValidIssuers = new string[]
            {
                tokenSetting.Issuer
            },
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
            ClockSkew= TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })

        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("x-tokenstatus-header", "fail");// may be not necessary for you
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
            options.Audience = tokenSetting.Audience;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = tokenSetting.RequireHttpsMetadata;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        });
```

and in

### Configure

```
        app.UseTokenProvider(); // This is my own middleware
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
```

### public class TokenProviderMiddleware {..}

```
public  Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IUserService userService)
        {

 if (!IsAuthenticationRequest(context.Request.Path, context.Request.Method)) {
                 return this._next(context);
            }

 var securityKey = "asdasdasdasdasdasddsda123123132123123";// your own key
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(securityKey);

        var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

  var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(listClaims, "Custom");

        var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
        {
            Audience = this._tokenSettings.Audience,
            Issuer = this._tokenSettings.Issuer,
            Subject = claimsIdentity,
            SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),

        };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var plainToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
        var signedAndEncodedToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(plainToken);

// signedAndEncodedToken => contains your token you can do send it as response or anything you want  

}



private bool IsAuthenticationRequest(string path, string method) {

    if (HttpMethods.IsPost(method) &&  path?.IndexOf("/api/login", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;           


 }
```

Do let me know if you need clarification on code..

Answer (score 0):

**This is an example, it suppose to help you or least give you a hint to how you can lead your work with in depth concept how things go. This is less secure though, read up on identity framework that's the recommended way to do it.**

You can either keep your access tokens dynamic (calling records from database matching with the sent values from the request source) or hard-code some in your middleware's Web.Config file.

for e.g (taking Db Approach for access tokens):

**db Table definition**

```
Create table Tokens(
id int identity(1,1) primary key,
userId int,
TokenValue varchar(max),
IsActive bit
)
```

**Custom models:**

```
public Class Error
{
  public string ErrMsg {get; set;}
} 

public Class ReturnData
{
  public Error ErrorObj {get; set;}
  public string UserName {get; set;}
  public string AccessToken {get; set;}
}
public class User
{
  public int UserId {get; set;}
  public string UserName {get; set;}
  public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

**in Api Controller:**

```
public ReturnData GetData(User Creds)
{
   ReturnData Data = new ReturnData();
   string Pass = Decrypt(Creds.Password);
   int i = //Code here to get the middle-ware access token from db table token and update token 'IsActive from 0 to 1' from database. 0 = false, 1 = true
   if(i > 0)
   {
     Data.AccessToken = Encrypt(DbTokenValue);
     Data.UserName = Creds.UserName; 

   }
   else
   {
     Error err = new  Error();
     err.ErrMsg = "something happened";
     Data.ErrorObj = err; 
   }
    return Data;  
}
```

then use this token for rest of the apis to make sure its the same user by comparing the token from db and give rights to do the operations.

Good luck.